# Wordpress Custom Post type page display

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am reading [Building wordpress themes from scratch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1477480994) in order to understand theme development.I got to a point in the book where it explains how to create the custom post type pages.And the author mentions that this function is required in order to display the page:

```
add_action('init' , 'director_rewrite');
function director_rewrite(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('typename','typename/%year%%postname%/' , true , 1);
    add_rewrite_rule('typename/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$','index.php?typename=$matches[2]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

I have deleted the function and the page still display corectly without it.That leads me to belive that I do not understand wha this actualy does.

So is this function required to properly display custom post type pages?If so what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds rewrite rule for the permalinks structure of your page. If you remove it, the page still show correctly, but link towards your page is different!